# why i am not able to access the packages installed with pip installer?

Tags: python-3.x

I installed some packages using pip installer but I am unable to access it in the python

I am trying to import some add-on packages into the code which I installed in my pc using pip installer but I am unable to import it in my code

Comment: This sounds like either different versions of python/pip or you are using different environments. That's almost always the problem in this sort of situation.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible reasons here

1. The packages are installed in a different environment and you are trying to import it in a different environment. You may installed a package in a virtual environment for project_1 and trying to import it in project_2 which is under different different.
2. The way you are importing package is different. Generally package names are directly used in the way it is installed.
   E.g requests module, it is installed as
   `pip install requests`
   and used as
   `import requests` in python code.
   But in case of opencv(package used for image processing) is installed as `pip install opencv-python` but used as `import cv2` in the code. Refer to the documentation of the package installed to check how to import it in the code.

You have to check for the possible case.